# Sample from a distribution if only mean median max etc. are given

Tags: r, distributions, python

Could I generate samples from a distribution that I only know its:
 **mean, median, mode, standard deviation, min, max, three of the percentiles**

If possible, I want to plot *histogram* of this distribution in *R* or *python*, but others are also acceptable. Any clues?

Comment: There are an infinite number of such distributions (any that take 6 parameters).

Comment: Of course, could you give me an example?

Comment: You need to chose a distribution type also. Depending on your values, not all may fit though. Try a Gaussian first